# how can we make camera capture screen modal in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can we make a camera picture frame for capturing a picture "modal"  - meaning the screen area for the camera that will take a picture of a credit card would not be showing the background object (before taking the picture)?

How can I achieve this using swift ?

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? Are you trying to present a UIImagePickerController modally? I don't know what you mean when you say "not be showing the background object"; do you mean the camera doesn't show anything until the user takes a photo? Could you provide some code as to how much you've already done?

Comment: I am trying to present "cardIOView" obtained from "CardIOViewDelegate" modally. what i mean is by default, the frame which is shown to take picture is not presented modally. you can still see the background object from the picture frame.

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.cardIOView.delegate = self
        self.cardIOView.scanInstructions = "Take a pic"
        self.cardIOView.scannedImageDuration = 0.0
        self.cardIOView.hideCardIOLogo = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        CardIOUtilities.preload()
    }

Comment: For the above code my class is implementing CardIOViewDelegate

Comment: If you run this code, you will see that card picture frame for taking picture is not presented "modally". it shows the background objects.

Comment: I don't have any experience with CardIO and you should've made that clear in your question, so I probably can't help.